# Iphone memory leak

Tags: iphone

Dealloc method is never calling in my program..if i release which is allocated in dealloc method then the release will happen or not?

Comment: can u please tell us the type of class u had made

Comment: I used UIViewController in view based application..

Comment: so u wanna say that u had made a viewController class and the dellock method is never calling......How is it possible

Comment: so how to check its calling or not..i used nslog in dealloc method to print some msg but its never printed in consol.

Comment: when i doo leak test it showing leak even if released in delloc method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on the calling of dealloc. Your app is quit and therefore all objects are killed anyway.

If you need to clean up (like closing a database) you should to that in applicationWillTerminate or applicationWillEnterBackground (I am not sure about the exact name).